# How do I use Apache::Reload under ActiveState Perl on Windows?

Tags: perl, mod-perl, activestate

I work with Activestate Perl on Windows and Apache.
I want to run my scripts under mod_perl.
To prevent Apache from caching modules during development I want to use Apache::Reload module.

I have added the following lines to httpd.conf

```
PerlModule Apache::Reload
PerlInitHandler Apache::Reload
PerlModule Apache2::RequestUtil
```

Then I restart Apache.
And then all my scripts produce Internal Server Error (500).

There are no errors in Apache log.

Do you know am I wrong or Apache::Reload just does not work on Windows?

Comment: I have used `Apache::Reload` through many versions of the module, perl, mod_perl and apache. It works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It definitely works on Windows.

Do you have these lines in your httpd.conf as well?

```
PerlSwitches -wT
LoadFile "C:\Perl\bin\perl510.dll"
LoadModule perl_module modules/new/mod_perl.so

LoadFile bin/libapreq2.dll
LoadModule apreq_module modules/mod_apreq2.so
```